# Stop executing doInbackground() method of AsyncTask when user swipe screen

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my android application i am fetching song lyrics online.This task is executed in background  using AsyncTask class. In doInbackground() i am calling method of another class for fetching lyrics.I want to stop executing method of other class from mycurrent activity using cancel() method of AsyncTask. But it doesn't stop execution of method outside current activity. Is there any way to stop executing that method execution ?

Here is my code..

```
    public class musicplayer extends Activity
    {
          DownloadWebPageTask task;

          public void playSong(int songIndex)
          {
             task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
             task.execute(new String[] { title, artist });
          }
          private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
          {
              @Override
              protected void onPreExecute() 
              {
            try 
            {
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.showLoading);
                } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) 
            {
                try 
            {
                 if(! isCancelled())
                 {
                // get lyrics
                lyricsArray = SearchHelper.findLyrics(arg0[0], arg0[1]);
                        publishProgress(OutputString);
                     }
                 else
                 {
                System.out.print("Cancelled");
                 }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                return artistArray;
            }
                @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... st) 
            {
                super.onProgressUpdate(st);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        tvMain.setText(Html.fromHtml(st[0].toString()));

                 }
                @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float                             velocityX,float velocityY) 
        {
                 try 
             {
                        task.cancel(true);
            playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                     }
                } 
}
```

Comment: have you tried to cancel AsyncTask execution in Activity onpause ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to stop your `AsyncTask` when your main activity is not running or is not the focus of the user. Based on that:

When your Activity loses focus the system calls `onPause()` followed by `onStop()`. Applications do all their cleaning-up by overriding these two function of `Activity`. So either in `onPause()` or `onStop()`, you should add:

```
    DownloadWebPageTask.cancel(true)
```

For this to work, you should have `static` access to the Task class.

[Update] You can also do it in `onDestroy()`, which is called when the activity is killed.

[Update] If you want to cancel the task only when user swipes, then use `onFling()` event listener like this:

```
    SimpleOnGestureListener simpleOnGestureListener = new SimpleOnGestureListener(){

         @Override
         public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,){
          // handle swipe event
         }
    };
```

Also check out [Gesture Overlay View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html) if you want to detect swipes over widgets

Comment: but..its not working for this code.Still the method of another class is invoked .

Comment: Is your onFling() being called? Log whatever is happening with `Log.d`.

Comment: yes..it is called..and {task.cancle(true);} is also executed but if i swipe screen very fast then background process is not stopped properly.